# Using the Squeeze Theorem to evaluate $\lim_{x\to0}\sqrt[3]{x}\cos(\ln(x^4))$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

So I have this limit here:

> $$\lim_{x\to0}\sqrt[3]{x}\cos(\ln(x^4))$$

Would this just be a simple application of the Squeeze Theorem? (I can't use L'hopital or Taylor polynomials.)

$$-\sqrt[3]{x}\leq\sqrt[3]{x}\cos(\ln(x^4))\leq\sqrt[3]{x}$$

The limit from both sides is $0$, so the middle limit must also be $0$. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. You know this because cos(x) is always bounded by -1 and 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right. Since
$$
-1\leq \cos(\ln(x^4)) \leq 1
$$
for all $x$ ($\neq 0$)
you indeed have
$$
-\sqrt[3]{x}\leq\sqrt[3]{x}\cos(\ln(x^4))\leq\sqrt[3]{x}
$$

and so
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} -\sqrt[3]{x} = 
\lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt[3]{x} = 0
$$
by the Squeeze Theorem the function in the middle will also have limit $0$:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt[3]{x}\cos(\ln(x^4)) = 0.
$$